# Java's switch equivalent in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, language-features

Is there an equivalent for Java's `switch` construct in Clojure? If yes, what is it? If no, do we have to use `if` `else` ladder to achieve it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try the `case` macro:

```
(case (+ 2 3)
  6 "error"
  5 "ok")
```

or with default value

```
(case (+ 2 3)
  5 "ok"
  "error")
```

Remember that according to the documentation

> The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time literals, and need not be quoted. (...)

See more examples at [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/case).

Comment: If your test values are non-literals, you might also want to look into `condp`: `(condp = (+ 2 3) (inc 4) "Ok" (dec 7) "error")`.

Comment: @Jan Using `case` of clojure is slowing down the process (noticeable time), is there any other alternative?

Comment: @vikbehal, there's also `cond`, as pointed out in mikera's answer. I'm really interested to learn what might be the cause of this slowdown. Could you do some research, e.g. profiling, and share the results?

Answer (score 42):

[case](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/case) is a good option as pointed out by Jan

[cond](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/cond) is also very useful in many related circumstances, particularly if you want to switch on the basis of evaluating a range of different conditional expressions, e.g.

```
(defn account-message [balance]
  (cond 
    (< balance 0) "Overdrawn!"
    (< balance 100) "Low balance"
    (> balance 1000000) "Rich as creosote"
    :else "Good balance"))
```

Note that the result of cond is determined by the first matching expression, so a negative balance will display "Overdrawn!" even though it also matches the low balance case.

[I have edited the code - removed the extra bracket at the end to make it work]

Comment: Nice reference to the Discworld :)

Comment: Note that `cond` will return `nil` if none of the conditions are satisfied!

Answer (score 8):

Though @Jan and @mikera suggestions to use [`case`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/case) or [`cond`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/cond) (may I add [`condp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/condp) to the list?) are sound from a functional¹ standpoint and though `case` 's limitations (e.g. test values can only be compile-time constants ; a default return value is mandatory) mirror those of `switch` there are some subtle differences:

- `case` cannot be used with Java `Enum` constants ;
- `case` 's dispatch is based on hashing AFAIK which makes it comparable to hashmaps in terms of performance ;  `switch` is way faster ;
- you cannot fall-through with `case`, which means that you must use other options (`condp` with value sets ?) to mirror `switch` 's behaviour.

---

[¹] not functional as in [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming), functional as in fulfilling a function, serving a purpose.